# using javascript and json create a table and use filter column

Tags: javascript, json, html

i m need od this output using  javascript and html,json.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Tamil Mani",
    "year": 1,
    "gender": "m",
    "marks": [
      {
        "sub": "Tamil",
        "mark": 98
      },
      {
        "sub": "English",
        "mark": 65
      },
      {
        "sub": "Maths",
        "mark": 88
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Amuthan",
    "year": 1,
    "gender": "m",
    "marks": [
      {
        "sub": "Tamil",
        "mark": 89
      },
      {
        "sub": "English",
        "mark": 79
      },
      {
        "sub": "Maths",
        "mark": 79
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Mugilan",
    "year": 1,
    "gender": "m",
    "marks": [
      {
        "sub": "Tamil",
        "mark": 97
      },
      {
        "sub": "English",
        "mark": 89
      },
      {
        "sub": "Maths",
        "mark": 99
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Tamil Oviya",
    "year": 1,
    "gender": "f",
    "marks": [
      {
        "sub": "Tamil",
        "mark": 89
      },
      {
        "sub": "English",
        "mark": 87
      },
      {
        "sub": "Maths",
        "mark": 97
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Amutha",
    "year": 1,
    "gender": "f",
    "marks": [
      {
        "sub": "Tamil",
        "mark": 89
      },
      {
        "sub": "English",
        "mark": 69
      },
      {
        "sub": "Maths",
        "mark": 79
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Mugil Mathi",
    "year": 1,
    "gender": "f",
    "marks": [
      {
        "sub": "Tamil",
        "mark": 97
      },
      {
        "sub": "English",
        "mark": 89
      },
      {
        "sub": "Maths",
        "mark": 99
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

this is the json file.

Comment: What do you want to do by using JSON file ?

Comment: Ask your question or doubt in good words.

Comment: i have to show these data in a table,by loading this users.json file in javascript..if u give ur mail id means ill share the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSON object, you can loop through it to construct what you need. I won't write it with your example, but a simplified one so that you can learn by doing rather than just copying and pasting. Hope it helps.

```
var people = [
    {
        name: "Adam"
    },
    {
        name: "Betty"
    },
    {
        name: "Charles"
    }
];

var html = people.reduce((accum, person) => {
    return accum + `<tr><td>${person.name}</td></tr>`;
}, '<table>') + '</table>';

// or if you're used to imperitive...
var html = '<table>';
people.forEach(person => {
    html += `<tr><td>${person.name}</td></tr>`;
});
html += '</table>';
```